# Oxidation numbers of atoms in Ti(SeO3)2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

What are the oxidation numbers of atoms in $\ce{Ti(SeO3)2}$? I'm having trouble figuring this out since I don't know the charge for either $\ce{Ti}$ or $\ce{Se}$.

Answer (score 3):

The [selenite anion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenite_(ion)) ($\ce{SeO3^{2-}}$) has a net charge of -2. Titanium's oxidation state should be obvious given this information. As for selenium's oxidation state, since we know each oxygen has a charge of -2, and since the entire polyatomic anion has a net charge of -2, the following equation must balance:

$$\ce{Se}+3 \cdot (-2)=-2$$

Comment: Is that just one of the polyatomic ions i should know by memory or is there a method of knowing that?

Comment: Selenium polyatomic anions are analogous to the sulfur polyatomic anions; e.g. sulfate ($\ce{SO4^{2-}}$) and selenate ($\ce{SeO4^{2-}}$), sulfite ($\ce{SO3^{2-}}$) and selenite ($\ce{SeO3^{2-}}$)

Comment: Selenite is maybe not one that you should have memorized, but sulfite $\ce{SO3^2-}$ is. You can use what you know about the similarities in chemical behavior of the elements in the same group to make an inference about $\ce{SO3^2-}$.